# Multiple column data extraction

Tags: google-sheets

Problem : I want to aggregate multiple conditions in discontinueted column.

Link : [Google Sheet link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Hc_BtpqFwxnrGeRwr7ejUmuuHDKDljnOHW2UlsGg7jY/edit#gid=1054707272)

Context: I'm a mushroom grower and I wanna schedule my production program for 2020. 
We call batch an amount of inoculated mushroom substrate put in production at the same time. Usually, it weights a ton, and for the total year 2020 we'll have about 40 batches put in production.

A batch has several characteristics :

- An **ID**. 20-B1 is the first batch for 2020, 20-B2 the second, and so on.
- A **scheduled week** of production start. Usually, the production for 1 batch last 14 week. The week of production is numbered from 1 to 14.
- A **calendar** week, where the array of 14 production week is placed.
- An **Origin**. We work with two companies (Eurosubstrat and CNC) and are producing our own substrate. This means 3 arguments: "EURO", "CNC" and "LCU"
- A **species cultivated**. We have two species: Shiitake and Pleurotus Ostreatus
- A **weight**; about 1 ton but few batches can be much lighter
- A **production capability** VS time: For example, in The third week of exploitation, a batch will produce 3,4% of his mass in mushroom.

I wanna extract and put the following results in a column :

Target 1 : In order to establish an order schedule, the amount of batch who match those criteria for 1 given calendar week; for example "Week production = 1" AND "Origin = Euro" AND "Species = shii."

[image: Target 1]

Target 2 : In order to estimate total production capability for 1 given species, the sum of individual production capability for 1 given calendar week: for example "Species = shii" AND (related)  "production capability"

[image: Target 2]

Hope I'm clear

If you imagine a better way to organize my data, feel free to suggest. I don't know if the current organization is the best.

Sorry, English is not my native tongue.

Comment: please share an example of desired result you want